# git whitespace woes

Tags: git, settings, whitespace

### Conflicts on whitespace suck

Whitespace has ended up being a horrible pain for me
while using git.

```
git config apply.whitespace=strip
```

seems to highten your chances of getting conflicts (as you strip
unneeded whitespace and then other collaborators see the stripped
whitespace as a change to their commits?)

I've tried a few other configurations for `apply.whitespace` in the
past, and maybe one of the other configs solves this, or maybe there's
other settings to deal with whitespace that I just haven't come
across, but I haven't yet found a clear way to get where I want to be.

### I want to silently resolve whitespace conflicts:

I never want to have another conflict on whitespace.  If another
committer alters whitespace, or I alter whitespace and then have to
merge against my own conflicts, *i really don't want to know about it*.
If someone changes my code from K&R style to One True Brace style by
changing whitespace, I'd prefer git allow either whitespace setup to win out over having to
see conflicts about it. I just don't care enough about whitespace to want to see conflicts about it.

So... ...is there any way that I can configure git to do that?

*If it makes any difference, here's my git version, and my current
config:*

```
tchalvak:~/ninjawars$ git --version
git version 1.6.0.4

tchalvak:~/ninjawars$
git config --list
color.branch=auto
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch.current=yellow reverse
color.branch.local=yellow
color.branch.remote=green
color.diff.meta=yellow bold
color.diff.frag=magenta bold
color.diff.old=red bold
color.diff.new=green bold
color.status.added=yellow
color.status.changed=green
color.status.untracked=cyan
gui.recentrepo=/home/tchalvak/zd/htdocs/cms
apply.whitespace=strip
user.name=****
user.email=****
alias.co=checkout
github.user=tchalvak
github.token=****
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=...@github.com:tchalvak/ninjawars.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Git1.6.0.4](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.6.0.4.txt) seems a bit old, especially if you consider that:

- in [1.6.3.4](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.6.3.4.txt), "`git apply --whitespace=fix`" did not fix trailing whitespace on an
  incomplete line
- in [1.6.3.2](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.6.3.3.txt), "`whitespace`" attribute that is set was meant to detect all errors known
  to git, but it told git to ignore trailing carriage-returns.

Could you try with Git1.6.4.1, and rather than setting a global config, set an attribute on the files you want a special whitespace handle, like this [patch describes](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/6/12/2112874/thread).

In a given directory, create a `.gitattributes` file.

```
* -whitespace
```

which will ignore any 'whitespace' errors.

Now that will not prevent any conflict due to lack of consistency but that may be worth  trying.

---

The patch was a test about:

> Only ignore whitespace errors in `t/tNNNN-*.sh` and the `t/tNNNN` subdirectories.
>   Other files (like test libraries) should still be checked.

```
t/.gitattributes
t[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*.sh  -whitespace
t[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/*     -whitespace
```

---

Note (Git 2.3.2+, Q1 2015, [commit 0a80bc9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a80bc9f13bf4373778e787b3a050f5b784faf30), by Junio C Hamano aka [`gitster`](https://github.com/gitster)) "`git apply --whitespace=fix`" is no longer silent:

> "`git apply --whitespace=fix`" fixed whitespace errors in the common
>   context lines but did so without reporting.
>
> When the incoming patch has whitespace errors in a common context line (i.e. a line that is expected to be found and is not modified by the patch), "`apply --whitespace=fix`" corrects the whitespace errors the line has, in addition to the whitespace error on a line that is updated by the patch.
>   However, we did not count and report that we fixed whitespace errors on such lines.

Comment: *nods*  Yeah, I've been using the git binary in the ubuntu repositories, but perhaps it's time that I got a bit closer to the most recent versions, maybe that'll help with the issue.

I'll also see what difference the .gitattributes setting makes on the situation.

Comment: 'lright, I've (happily) added the launchpad ppa for the latest stable version of git in ubuntu, hopefully that'll fix things up.

Comment: Upgrading does seem to have solved some of the issues that I had in the past.

Comment: @Karl: I am not able to find that same article again, so I link to a Git patch which illustrate the same idea (setting a git attribute for a specific file in order to ignore whitespace warnings/errors)

Answer (score 9):

If you are going to turn on those settings, you need to schedule a day where ALL source code in your project gets its whitespace uniformly stripped, by running a script, or by saving every file from an editor that will perform the strip on save.  Then, all future commits will be policed by the settings, so all should be well going forward.