# Git merge ignore spaces

Tags: git, git-merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git whitespace woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316364/git-whitespace-woes)

How can I setup get to not report conflicts purely due to whitespace on a merge, like the following ?

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    open RESDBFILE, "< $this_day_result_file_";
    while ( my $resdbline_ = <RESDBFILE> )
    {
        my @rwords_ = split ' ', $resdbline_;
        if ( exists $uncaliberated_strategies_{$rwords_[0]} )
        { # if this strategy_filename_base was there in @strategy_filevec_
        delete $uncaliberated_strategies_{$rwords_[0]};
        }
    }
    close RESDBFILE;
=======
      open RESDBFILE, "< $this_day_result_file_";
      while ( my $resdbline_ = <RESDBFILE> )
      {
    my @rwords_ = split ' ', $resdbline_;
    if ( exists $uncaliberated_strategies_{$rwords_[0]} )
    { # if this strategy_filename_base was there in @strategy_filevec_
        delete $uncaliberated_strategies_{$rwords_[0]};
    }
      }
      close RESDBFILE;
>>>>>>> origin/stable
```

Comment: If it doesn't report it, how is it going to make the merge?  Arbitrarily pick one to use?

Comment: @Andy Very good question! According to the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies) for the `ignore-all-space` option: "If _their_ version only introduces whitespace changes to a line, _our_ version is used. If _our_ version introduces whitespace changes but _their_ version includes a substantial change, _their_ version is used."

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
$ git merge -s ignore-all-space
```

For more details:

```
$ git help merge
/whitespace
```

Comment: `git merge -Xignore-all-space` works for me...maybe its a version thing...

Comment: Same goes for `git cherry-pick -Xignore-all-space`. At least on the (almost) current version.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the [core.whitespace config](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_core_whitespace) to see if that helps.

Comment: That won't. core.whitespaces is about the set of problems to warn about, not about merge.