# How can I ignore whitespace in the NetBeans merge tool

Tags: git, netbeans, merge, whitespace, ignore

How do I ignore leading and trailing whitespace in NetBeans when resolving conflicts during a git merge.

Under Option > Miscellaneous > Diff you can set the diff tool to ignore leading an trailing whitespace but this does not take affect in the NetBeans merge tool.

git supports `git merge -Xignore-all-space`. Is there as way to pass this flag in NetBeans?

[Git Merge and Fixing Mixed Spaces and Tabs with two Branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256769/git-merge-and-fixing-mixed-spaces-and-tabs-with-two-branches)

Answer (score 0):

Evan now (2018, 5 years later), that does not seem to be possible through NetBeans alone, if you consider its [Git User Guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/ide/git.html#branchMerge):

[image: https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/73/ide/git/merge-small.png]

You cannot pass any merge flag to NetBeans, and [you cannot set a git config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6956669/6309).
That means a regular `git merge -Xignore-all-space` in command line remains the safest road.