# Ignore whitespace for only certain file extensions when merging

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, git-merge

I have this command

```
git merge -Xignore-all-space origin/dev
```

scares me a little bit b/c I am afraid of merging a file where whitespace matters. Is there a way to limit it to certain files, something like this:

```
git merge -Xignore-all-space *.js origin/dev
```

Comment: If the question is not clear, whitespace matters for some languages, but not for others. I just want to ignore whitespace changes for languages where where whitespace is not that important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anytime you want to set a configuration per file extension, a good place to start is [`gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).
In a `.gitattributes` files, you can set a directive per file, or per file extension.

However, the *.js -whitespace I [mentioned in 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316595/6309) might not apply during a merge.

Since `ignore-all-space` is first a [`git diff` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff--w), you might need to set up a [diff driver](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#gitattributes-String) in a `.gitattributes` (again, only for `*.js` files), emulating [`--word-diff-regex`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---word-diff-regexltregexgt)

> Use `<regex>` to decide what a word is, instead of considering runs of non-whitespace to be a word
>
> Every non-overlapping match of the  is considered a word. Anything between these matches is considered whitespace and ignored(!) for the purposes of finding differences.
>
> You may want to append `|[^[:space:]]` to your regular expression to make sure that it matches all non-whitespace characters. A match that contains a newline is silently truncated(!) at the newline.

For example (to be tweaked in order to match what you need in a javascript file for a diff without spaces)

```
*.js    diff=js
[diff "js"]
    wordRegex = "[^[:space:]]+"
```

Comment: thanks, can you show what the `git` command at the command line would actually look like in full?

Comment: @AlexanderMills It is simpler to edit directly a `.gitattributes` file in the folder where the *.js files reside. Then test a merge (without completing it) to see if whitespace-only conflicts are ignored or not.